# Javascript simple syntax problem

Tags: javascript

I have this line of JS which I have determined is wrong.

```
classes[i] = document.getElementsByAttribute ("class", show_hide_class_selectors[i]);
```

In context

```
for (var i = 0; i< show_hide_class_selectors.length; i++) {
        classes[i] = document.getElementsByAttribute ("class", show_hide_class_selectors[i]);
        alert ("ok");
    }
```

Can someone see where this is wrong?

Comment: Do you know [getElementsByAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Method/getElementsByAttribute) only works on XUL elements, not standard W3C DOM elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You invented a non-standard `getElementsByAttribute` method on the `document` object, and the code is failing because it doesn't exist.

You should probably looking at using a selector engine; every major JS library includes one, and there are a number of [tiny implementations](http://microjs.com/#css) you can use.

Comment: +1, You should also suggest a library that simplifies finding elements with a certain class. Or suggest a modern browser that supports `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: Apparently its been longer than I thought since I used Javascript :) :(

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i< show_hide_class_selectors.length; i++) {
    classes[i] = document.getElementsByClassName (show_hide_class_selectors[i]);
    alert ("ok");
}
```

if however won't work in IE 6-8. Better use jQuery or another library, providing css selectors for JS

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous implementations for this function on the internet ([example](http://samsami2u.wordpress.com/2009/03/04/getelementsbyattribute-for-javascipt/)), but these are cusome implementations that expand the `document` object.

You can add it in yourself by placing it in your code.

Better still though, if you are wanting to do this sort of thing, then use a JavaScript library such as jQuery this handles all of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Erm, close, I suppose. You want `getElementsByClass`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < show_hide_class_selectors.length; i++) {
  classes[i] = document.getElementsByClass(show_hide_class_selectors[i]);
  alert("ok");
}
```